# Scrolling to the bottom of the webpage within a certain div element - Power Automate

Tags: javascript, power-automate

I'm trying to scrape some data from Linkedin - Sales Navigator, but I can only get info from 8/25 people because the page is not loading in full. I tried with PowerAutomate but the problem might be that the page contains different div elements, where you can scroll down.

It kind of worked on YT, where you have two scroll divs, but after the command got executed, the scrolling was stuck on that spot.

Does anyone have a good tutorial or can explain how to use it properly, or has a better solution? I found this, but I don't get it:

```js
function ExecuteScript() {
  function autoScrolling() {
    document.getElementByld('search-results-container').scrollTop -= 1000;
    /*window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);*/
  }
  setInterval(autoScrolling, 50);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.